# Docker python won't start even in python image

Tags: docker, jenkins

I tried to make Jenkinsfile, but there has been a problem with Python image. I could boil it down to this:

```
node(){

  checkout scm

  stage ('Build'){
    docker.image('python:3.6').withRun('')
      {
        sh 'python -V'
      }
}
```

Where I am receiveing error code

```
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/project_jenkins@tmp/durable-e35e2b30/script.sh: line 1: python: not found
```

What gives? Shouldn't python be installed by building the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
stage('Build') {
    docker.image('python:3.6').inside {
        sh 'python --version'
    }
}
```

What it does, it tells docker to instanciate a container with the python:3.6 image and mount the workspace inside it.

Comment: Yeah, you are right: I was supposed to use .inside() and not .withRun().